# What determines the values of weights in a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, neurons

I am trying to understand how weights are actually gotten. What is generating them in a neural network? What is the algorithm that gives them certain values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, weights are randomly initialized. Then, as the model is [optimized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#Optimization) for its given task, those weights are steadily made "better" as determined by the network's [loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function). This is also referred to as "training" the neural network.

By far the most popular way of updating weights in a neural net is the [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) algorithm, most simply with [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) (SGD). Essentially, the algorithm determines how much each individual weight contributed to the network's loss. It then updates that weight in the direction that would reduce the loss.

I recommend going through Michael Nielsen's [online book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @PhilipRaeisghasem, in most architectures, weights are initialized in a random manner. However, some research papers suggest applying a random normal distribution initialization to the weights in the case of Convolutional Neural Networks (for computer vision).

Comment: Absolutely. I didn't think getting into specific initialization distributions would be super beneficial for someone asking such a basic question. But you're right.

Comment: I absolutely overthought that question. Thanks for replying.